# MQL4 - How do I retrieve all values from only one dimension in a 3D Array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, mql4, mt4

As the title suggests, how do I retrieve all values from a single dimension in a multi-dimensional array?

```
int size = ArraySize(AllLetterPrices);
  for(int i=size-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
      Print(AllLetterPrices[i,Arr_ObjectTRUEPRICE,0]);
  
  }
```

This returns Array Out Of Range.
The index dimension of the Array is dynamic, whereas the second two dimensions are static as follows :

```
AllLetterPrices[index,0,0];
AllLetterPrices[index,1,0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following and remember that [ArraySize()](https://docs.mql4.com/array/arraysize) returns the total number of ALL elements of the array so you cannot use it as you have to count the size of only the first element. Use [ArrayRange()](https://docs.mql4.com/array/arrayrange) instead.

```
   int size = ArrayRange(AllLetterPrices,0);
   for(int i=size-1; i>=0; i--)
   {
      Print(AllLetterPrices[i][Arr_ObjectTRUEPRICE][0]);
   }
```